# Objective-C: Accessing a property of another class

Tags: objective-c, ios

Let's assume I have two classes (ClassA, ClassB)

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : SomeSuperClass

@property (some Attributes) ClassB *classB;
@property (some Attributes) NSString *someString;

@end
```

Now my problem:

I want to access the NSString someString in the classB instance. Whats the best way to achieve this?
I was thinking of the two solutions:

Creating a protocol in classB and let classA respond to this protocol. The only method in this protocol would be to access/change this string.

The second solution I came up with is give this string as a parameter after creating an instance of classB, then classB can store the reference to it and can change it whenever it wants.

Both of solution seem working to me (didn't test it, just assume it), but also they seem to me a bit of an overkill (especially the first one)

Let me know whats the best way to do this, Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example interface for ClassB? Like CodaFi suggested, a weak reference should be just fine. So long as you have something like: \@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString; defined in your .h file, and \@synthesize someString in your .m file (along with any overrides), you should be golden. I think ;-)

Comment: Note that you can't "store a reference" to a string and then change it and expect that change to be propagated to the place where you got the reference.  NSSting is immutable, and when you "update" one you really replace it with a new one with a different address.

Answer (score 3):

If you made a weak reference to B's parent (A), then you could safely access it's properties without resorting to overkill or creating retain cycles.

```
@interface ClassA : SomeSuperClass

@property (some Attributes) ClassB *classB;
@property (some Attributes) NSString *someString;

@end


@implementation

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classB = [[ClassB alloc]initWithParent:self];
    }
}

@end

@class ClassA;
@interface ClassB : SomeSuperClass

@property (nonatomic, weak) ClassA *classA;

-(id)initWithParent:(ClassA*)parent;

@end

#import "ClassA.h"
@implementation 

-(id)initWithParent:(ClassA*)parent {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classA = parent;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.classA.someString); //perfectly legal
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: then I still have to pass ClassA as a parameter to classB, right?

Comment: @c2programming No problem.  Weak references are awesome!

Comment: This question is asked at least once a week, and at certain parts of the year daily.  Please make an effort to find the answer on your own before asking.

Comment: @HotLicks Aw, go easy on the kid.  I mean, we were all beginners at some point (and trust me, I've got some pretty embarrassing questions/answers from my early days of programming up here).

Comment: @CodaFi -- Other people have their questions downvoted four times and then closed within 14 minutes.  I was being polite, relatively speaking.

Comment: @HotLicks Then at least begin the closing process.  I'd certainly vote this in as a duplicate in a heartbeat