# Objective-C properties of another class to be accessed in other methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that this question has been asked many a times in this forum, After going through those posts I did find a partial solution for the problem from one of the post, but I do have one doubt from this post [Objective-C: Accessing a property of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887047/objective-c-accessing-a-property-of-another-class).

I was able to access the values of the properties by the given answer, but was not able to use the same values of those properties in other instance methods of the child class. Can anybody give some examples on how to do the same.

**Update of the code**

```
@interface ClassA : SomeSuperClass

@property (some Attributes) ClassB *classB;
@property (some Attributes) NSString *someString;

@end


@implementation

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classB = [[ClassB alloc]initWithParent:self];
    }
}

@end

@class ClassA;
@interface ClassB : SomeSuperClass

@property (nonatomic, weak) ClassA *classA;

-(id)initWithParent:(ClassA*)parent;

@end

#import "ClassA.h"
@implementation 
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.classA.someString); //here I get null
}
-(id)initWithParent:(ClassA*)parent {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classA = parent;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.classA.someString); //perfectly legal and prints the string value
    }
}
```

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what precisely is not working for you. Post your code, show what you're trying to achieve and what you're getting instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @AndreyChernukha I did update the code.

Comment: @geeker - it's very tough to help when you ask in the abstract. Try to ask a specific question with specific code. Would be a good idea for you to review [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a singleton where it creates a single instance, and other class can use the same instance for accessing the properties.

Ex:

```
+(id)singletonInstance
{
  static classA *classA = nil;
  static dispatch_oce_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  // if the instance is not there then create an instance and init one.
  classA = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return classA;
}


// in the same class .m file viewDidLoad add the below code

//classA.m

classA *classA = [classA sharedInstance]; // this will be the instance which will be called by other classes (i.e classB ..etc).
```

Comment: Thank's for this will check and come back here if any queries.

Comment: Thanks @vishal now I'm able to get the properties :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) ClassA *classA;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassA *classA;
```

The reason why you are getting nil is because `ClassA` object is deallocated. It is deallocated because your weak reference does not retain it. Only strong references retain objects.  Read about ARC.

Change `ClassA` implementation to the following:

```
@interface ClassA : SomeSuperClass

@property (some Attributes) ClassB *classB;
@property (some Attributes) NSString *someString;

@end


@implementation

-(id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    _classB = [[ClassB alloc]initWithParent:self];
}
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // do you see this printed in console when you run the app?
    NSLog(@"DEALLOC!!!");
}

@end
```

Comment: I did the change which u suggested but was not able to get the value in viewDidLoad but the value did come up in initWithParent method correctly.

Comment: put - (void) dealloc{ NSLog(@"Dealloc"!); } Inside ClassA. Does it get called? Do you see Dealloc! printed?

Comment: can u give me fresh example of the same pls

Comment: It is very weird. Send me your project to nsobsession@gmail.com and I will send it back to you in five minutes

Comment: greatly appreciate your willingness to help me, I have sent you the code

Comment: No, buddy, send me the whole project, not just few files. I need to build and run it

Comment: Can u give me some hints on where I'm actually doing wrong, as the project is a little confidential I'm not supposed to share the entire codebase :(.

Comment: I can't. I need to run it. From what I see it should not get deallocated. But it does. There's no way for me to find out what is wrong without debugging it. What you can do is create a different little sample project which would simply reproduce your problem while omitting all the rest and send this new one to me

Comment: Sure will do that

Comment: can you please check your mail @AndreyChernukha

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in your code, please check the code carefully.

I infer that `SomeSuperClass` probably inherits from `UIViewController`

#### 1. Initialization does not return an instance object

All initialization methods should have a return value, the code you provide has no return value, you should change to this

```
- (instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classB = [[ClassB alloc]initWithParent:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

#### 2. `weak` modifier property

Generally, only `weak` is used to solve circular references. It should be avoided at other times and will be released immediately after use.

#### 3. `someString` property does not see initialization

#### 4. The order in which `ClassA` and `ClassB` enter

I assume that you solved the previous problem, and the order should be to enter `ClassA` first, then enter `ClassB`.

To enter `ClassB` from `ClassA`, you must use the initialized `classB` property, like this

```
ClassA.m

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.classB animated:YES];
```

Then finally execute `viewDidLoad` when `ClassB` is displayed, you can get the correct `someString`

Comment: Will surely correct any of my mistakes and will get back here soon thanks @nullable